# XAxis label angle in MPAndroidChart causes chart to move up

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

When i use xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45); to rotate the labels of the xAxis on a bar chart,it causes the chart to jump up on the charts.BarChart control.

[Chart without label rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4oHB.png)

[Chart with label rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg7iy.png)

How do i prevent this from happening while keeping the rotation?

Comment: try xaxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true) . Let me know the result.

Comment: Did not work. It still jumps up and down. and on inital search goes up if there is a bit longer text on x axis. The long text is the problem, but there should be a solution.

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: Okay, I may have found the issue, I did set the `combinedChart.setViewPortOffsets(100f, 50f, 0f, 100f);`. Removing this resolved the problem. Also labelRotationAngle do not cause to jump up on the charts. Because I am using the the labelRotation.